Unable to redirect to internal url after login using Sustainsys SAML 2.0 library for ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app
I'm using the AspNetCore2 package of Sustainsys libraries for my new ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web app. After successful login on the IDP Sign-On page, the application is stuck in a loop stating that initiating login to IDP entityId name and not redirecting to the internal/app URL or Index page. I am still determining what I am missing; any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
I added the Return URI attribute, which didn't affect the redirect behaviour.
Here's the code in the Program.cs file for my app:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription), System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url);
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha1SignatureDescription), System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url);

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Saml2Defaults.Scheme;
}).AddCookie()
.AddSaml2(option =>
{
    // Set up our EntityId, this is our application.
    option.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(builder.Configuration["app_entityId"]);
    option.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = SigningBehavior.Always;
    option.SPOptions.WantAssertionsSigned = true;
option.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(builder.Configuration["service_certificate"]));
// Add an identity provider.
option.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(builder.Configuration["Entity_Id"]), option.SPOptions)
{
    // Load config parameters from metadata, using the Entity Id as the metadata address.
    LoadMetadata = true,
    MetadataLocation = builder.Configuration["Provider_entity_Id"],
    WantAuthnRequestsSigned = true,
    AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true
});

The SignIn and Signout methods are in the AccountController where logic to redirect is defined:
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost, HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home")
    }, Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Defaults.Scheme);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost, HttpGet]
public IActionResult Signout()        
{
    var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Index), "Home", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme)
    };

    // you need these two in order for Sustainsys.Saml2 to successfully sign out
    AddAuthenticationPropertiesClaim(authProps, "/SessionIndex");
    AddAuthenticationPropertiesClaim(authProps, "/LogoutNameIdentifier");

    return SignOut(authProps, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Defaults.Scheme);
}

After successful login on the IDP page, the output in the VS shows the below description in loop but doesn't launch the Index page.

Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler: Information: Successfully processed SAML response _ea12f230-7a21-4f27-a0de-2e0bc2d60fdc and authenticated user d6cd57ea2fb8b88aee2e5854a6fc67b93919e969b*******************
Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler: Information: Initiating login to Provider_entityId name
Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler: Information: Successfully processed SAML response _2efa1361-1d52-4fc3-817f-dac7a8d6cf62 and authenticated  d6cd57ea2fb8b88aee2e5854a6fc67b93919e969b*******************
Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler: Information: Initiating login to Provider_entityId name


What is the response from the /Saml2/Acs endpoint? Is it a redirect? To where? Is there any cookie set?
